# >>> operator in python

Tags: python, operator-keyword

ActionScript and javascript supports '>>>' operator. I am converting an actionscript of base64 encoding/decoding using python. I know base64 is available and this is for learning purpose. python doesn't have "..." operator.
[base64 action script](http://lostinactionscript.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/library/com/lia/crypto/AES.as)

in decode function you have two lines

1. o1 = bits >>> 16 & 0xff;
2. o2 = bits >>> 8 & 0xff;

How do I convert these lines into python?

Comment: What does the operator *do*? Arithmetic right-shift? (Things like `>>>` are hard to Google, so please *name* them.)

Comment: btw. if you need AES in Python, just use PyCrypto package. http://pycrypto.org/

Comment: It's an arithmetic shift right (ASR), as opposed to a logical shift right (LSR). I still wish one of these languages would implement the rotate instructions (ROL and ROR), but those depend on an exact number of bits, and some processors let you rotate through the carry bit, so it gets messy. Oh, BTW, `bits >>> 16 & 0xff` and `bits >> 16 & 0xff` are the same thing as long as `bits` is at least 24 bits long, due to the masking performed by the `&` operator. Same for the other equation. In English, these equations just extract single bytes from a larger integer field.

Comment: I don't think this is a good way to learn Python. At best you'll learn the syntax. But you will miss the opportunity to learn the right concepts in you new language. Worst case you will learn things that are wrong in Python. Also your script is horribly low level, something like this should never be implemented in Python. You should learn to use the right libraries and modules instead.

Answer (score 3):

IINM, `>>>` is a right shift that preserves the value of the leftmost bit. This has the effect of keeping the sign of the number intact (i.e. negative numbers get a 1 inserted as their MSB instead of a 0).

In Python, integers can be arbitrarily big. There is no meaningful concept of a most significant bit since the number of bits is not bounded. Right shifts therefore simply shift all bits to the right and preserve the sign. So, in Python you can just use `>>`.

Edit:

As @Sven Marnach has pointed out, the `>>>` operation does the exact opposite of what I thought it did in Javascript. Thus `>>>` does not preserve sign, while `>>` appears to do so. Another interesting fact is that apparently `-1>>1` is `-1` and not `0` in Javascript. Needless to say, my knowledge of Javascript is really limited and I am not sure what the exact equivalent of these operators are in Python.

One options might be to explicitly limit how many bits are being used (perhaps by using `ctypes.c_int`) and then set the left most bit manually as desired in a user defined right shift function.

Comment: This is not true. `>>>` does *not* preserve sign: Try `javascript:alert(-3>>>1);`

Answer (score 0):

```
import ctypes
#convert signed to unsigned
bits = ctypes.c_uint32(bits).value

o1 = bits >> 16 & 0xff
o2 = bits >> 8 & 0xff
```

Comment: The operator `>>` does something different than `>>>` in JavaScript, and the difference matters in this context.